# MIPS/QtSpim Register 1 is reserved for assembler error

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I am trying to write an assembler program in MIPS and when I try to use a for loop without pseudoinstructions, I get the error in QtSpim that says "Register 1 is reserved for assembler on line 16 of file E:/Rechnerorganisation/Qtspim/Rechneruebung Vorgaben/minimum_finden.s
  slt $at, $t0, $a1 #slt (i". Can anyone help me?

```
findminimum:
addi    $t0, $zero, 1       #int i = 1
add     $t1, $zero, $zero   #beginn vom laden von int min = a[0]
sll     $t1, $t1, 2
add     $t1, $a0, $t1
lw      $t1, 0($t1)         #min = a[0
for:slt     $at, $t0, $a1       #slt (i<n) # line 16
beq     $at, $zero, endfor  #if(i>=n) go to endfor
sll     $t2, $t0, 2     
add     $t2, $a0, $t2
```

Comment: MIPS has a boatload of other regs, so the easiest thing is just to use `$t3`.  You only need to get your assembler to let you use `$at` if you've used up `$t0` .. `$t9` and don't have any other `$a` or `$v` or other registers you want to clobber.  (Not that there's anything wrong with using `$at`, or asking if you're curious.)

Answer (score 1):

According to some [google group post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ucb.class.cs61c/mf9ZUSCfOqQ) you can switch off the `at` being reserved for assembler only temporarily by:

```
    .set noat   # switch off assembler warning about $at usage
    ... your code using $1 ...
    .set at     # switch on assembler warning about $at usage
```

Didn't verify myself, I have only MARS installed, and there I can exploit `at` without any warning or error, just on my own risk (of not recognizing where I use `at` by pseudo instruction in hidden way - but I debug always with full disassembly, so I would catch such problem early).

edit: it's also mentioned in [spim documentation](http://spimsimulator.sourceforge.net/HP_AppA.pdf), so it should work.